# How to use LINQ replace a range of nested values in a list?

Tags: c#, linq, struct, point, addrange

I'm probably not wording the question correctly, so please help me on the nomenclature.

If I have a `List<Point>` which has a constant set of `x` values, but a variable stream of `y` values.  Right now I have:

```
List<DataPoint> points = new List<DataPoint>();
while(...)
{
    double data[] = ...
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        points.Add(new DataPoint(i, data[i]));
}
```

But I feel like it should be possible to use LINQ:

```
points.Select(y => y.AddRange(data));
```

I don't need to change the `x` values.  Also, I'm asking because I'm trying to increase processing performance on this loop somehow, so if there's a *faster way*, please enlighten me.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not modifying data. IMO, a loop would be much clear option when it comes to code readability. There might not be any performance gain with LINQ

Comment: You could probably convert data to a List<double> and do a join with LINQ and assign the result to `points`.

Comment: *"...which has a **constant** set of x values"* sounds like array to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to create all the values you want to add then use `AddRange`.

```
var newPoints = data.Select((d,i) => new DataPoint(i, d));
points.AddRange(newPoints);
```

But please note that this will probably not be any faster than your `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Simpler, but harder to read. And you're right: almost identical performance.